# how to change the event_calendar plugin to show by week instead by month?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to customize the table builder plugin for a week calendar ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397863/how-to-customize-the-table-builder-plugin-for-a-week-calendar)

im using the event_calendar plugin , the git repository:

https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar

i need to customize this calendar to show by the week and not by month, how can i do it?

this is my controller:

```
def index
    do_withs = DoWith.where(:friend_id => current_user.id)
    @statuses = do_withs.collect { |f| f.status_id }
    @statuses = @statuses.collect { |f| Status.find(f) }
    @statuses = @statuses + current_user.statuses 
    @statuses.flatten!
    @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
  end
```

and this is my view :

```
<div id="calendar">
  <h2 id="month">
     <%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
    <%=h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
 <%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
  </h2>
  <% calendar_for @statuses, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
    <%= calendar.head('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') %>
    <% calendar.day(:day_method => :date) do |date, statuses| %>
      <%= date.day %>
      <ul>
        <% for status in statuses %>
          <li><%= link_to h(status.content), status %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

its driving me crazy for couple of days now, please please please if someone know how can i custom this calendar let me know.
thanks allot.

Comment: It looks like you haven't done much research into how you would accomplish this. If you have any paths you took that didn't work out place them in the post so we don't research the same dead ends.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399810/how-to-customize-the-table-builder-plugin-for-a-week-calendar
Which is also an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397863/how-to-customize-the-table-builder-plugin-for-a-week-calendar

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is very limited in functionality and it's impossible to display events by weeks.

There is an alternative solution based on jQuery.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

and I just found rails backend for it:

https://github.com/bokmann/rails3_fullcalendar